# z-index layering in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael, z-index

I'm using Raphael to draw different shapes in different layers. I'd like to implement CSS z-index layering so that no matter which function is executed first(draw_rect, draw_circle or draw_line), the rectangle stays at the bottommost layer, the line, in the middle and the circle at the topmost layer. Here's what I've tried:

```
draw_rect(10, 10, 180, 180); 
draw_circle(100, 100, 60);
draw_line();
function draw_rect(x, y, width, height) {
  var rect = paper.rect(x, y, width, height);
  rect.attr({
    fill: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    'z-index': 1
  });
}
function draw_circle(x, y, radius) {
  var circ = paper.circle(x, y, radius);
  circ.attr({
    fill: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
    'z-index': 3
  });
}
function draw_line() {
  var line = paper.path("M0,0L200,200");
  line.attr({
    'stroke': 'blue',
    position: 'absolute',
    'z-index': 2
  });
}
```

I can't use element.tofront() & element.toback() since the expressions bring the elements to the top/bottom layers only (not the middle layer). So, if somebody could enlighten me on doing the z-index layering, I'd be thankful for eternity :D

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can't do this with z-index, unless you separate them into separate svg containers maybe (eg overlaying papers), as the SVG spec uses ordering to decide position.

Also there is no z-index 'attribute', its a style, so would need to be set via CSS (ie on the SVG container).

Otherwise you will have to do it via DOM ordering. You can possibly use something like el.insertBefore()/After() to help position them into the correct place, but that may need you to include a bit of extra logic. Eg you could place each one in a set and check them as you go, or use a selectAll statement to see if previous ones have been drawn, so you can add them before/after.

Comment: I know that I can check every time I create new objects but I just thought that z-indexing will be a hell lot easier if it can be implemented. Checking becomes a problem when you have so many objects on so many different layers.

Comment: Maybe it would help to explain why they would be coming in random order, and how you would know what order they need to be in beforehand, as this may help figure an intuitive solution.

Comment: i'm trying to draw a map that shows real time connection between the nodes. so the map's at the lowest z-index level. and the connections are represented by the lines connecting the centers of the nodes(circles). The position of the circles, as well as the lines are changing (randomly). but if I can't do the z-indexing, and I draw the lines after the circles, the lines will be drawn on the circles. I want the circles to be overlapping(on higher z-index than the lines).

Comment: You could possibly put the circles on one SVG with a different zindex, and the lines on another overlayed if that would help (so basically have 3 papers, one for map, another for circles, another for lines.

Comment: So, basically, it's impossible to implement z-indexing on just one paper?

Comment: Yes, afaik thats the case, ordering is done via ordering in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I'm enlightened :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line.toFront()` to move the required layer to the front.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).